# Evaluate this limit in terms of f

Tags: limits

I want to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim_{d\to x} \dfrac{\dfrac{2x}{f'(x)}+f(x)-f(d)-\dfrac{x^2-d^2}{f(x)-f(d)}}{2\left(\dfrac{d-x}{f(x)-f(d)}+\dfrac{1}{f'(x)}\right)}$$

I tried L'hopital's rule but it just keeps getting worse and worse.

I got this limit by wondering about circles fitting on a curve at a point $(x,f(x))$ and this limit is the $x$ coordinate of the circles center, in terms of a dummy point $d$.

Comment: Do you know the limit-based definition of $f'(d)$? Can you write it out for us? Do you see anything like that anywhere in your numerator or denominator?

Comment: May be, you could start developing $f(d)$ as a Taylor series built at $d=x$.

Comment: @JohnHughes I've tried that, but it yields a 0/0 and l'hopital makes it even messier and still a 0/0 if I've done it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't pretty, but it works:

Multiply the top and bottom by $f'(x)(f(x)-f(d))$ to clear denominators, giving:
$$
\lim_{d \to x} \frac{2x(f(x)-f(d))+f'(x)(f(x)-f(d))^2-f'(x)(x^2-d^2)}{2(f(x)-f(d)-f'(x)(x-d))}
$$
By adding $(x-d)^2f'(x)-(x-d)^2f'(x)$ to the numerator, this becomes
$$
\lim_{d \to x} \frac{2x(f(x)-f(d))-2xf'(x)(x-d) + f'(x)(f(x)-f(d))^2+f'(x)(x-d)^2}{2(f(x)-f(d)-f'(x)(x-d))}
$$
$$
 = x + \lim_{d \to x} \frac{f'(x)(f(x)-f(d))^2+f'(x)(x-d)^2}{2(f(x)-f(d)-f'(x)(x-d))}
$$

Now use L'Hopital's Rule, differentiating with respect to $d$, to give:
$$
=x+ \lim_{d \to x} \frac{-2f'(x)f'(d)(f(x)-f(d))-2f'(x)(x-d)}{2f'(x)-2f'(d)}
$$
This is still an indeterminate form, so cancel the $2$'s, and use L'Hopital's Rule again:
$$
=x + \lim_{d \to x} \frac{f'(x)f'(d)^2-f'(x)f''(d)(f(x)-f(d)) + f'(x)}{-f''(d)} 
$$
$$
=x - \lim_{d \to x} \frac{f'(x)f'(d)^2+f'(x)}{f''(d)}
$$
$$
=x - \frac{f'(x)+(f'(x))^3}{f''(x)}
$$
As long as $f''(x) \neq 0$.